# Remove the unknown format in Cell styles

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

While copying the data from different workbook, importing of ranges created a mess as shown in the pic. Steps to see Home tab--styles ribbon--cell styles

Not sure how to fix this.
[image]

Kinldy help.

Comment: That fetches me anrun-time error of 1004.Delete Method of style class failed.

Comment: i did all research and nothing worked. But someone without sense has downgraded this question which i am could not fix for last 2 days. Adding to it manual delete of those styles too dont work.

Comment: Apologies. manual deletion does  not work at all.something fishy..trying to understand.

Comment: No. i have confirmed that. Its still healthy and working. We are building features on top of that.Something else which is hidden.

Comment: So if manual deletion does not work, it seems that it's something specific to that workbook. Would you mind publishing it so we can  have a look at the problem as the way it's now I'm afraid we cannot reproduce it. It's the workbook protected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked this out in at least one instance - didn't find it on the web so hopefully helps you if you have the same issue...

add code to "unlock" or unprotect the style first before deleting it.  Below is the code modified from the Mr Excel (I think) forum...

```
    For Each styT In ActiveWorkbook.Styles
        If Not styT.BuiltIn Then
            styT.Locked = False
            styT.Delete
        End If
    Next styT
```

Comment: styT.Locked = False is not unlocked some styles for me.